# dynamically replacing text in Labelfield

Tags: blackberry

I'm wondering if there is a way to take the text set within a LabelField and have it so the text is replaced, be it by a buttonClick, keyPress, or what have you. Did a bit of digging around the rim API documents and the best I could find was appendLabelText(), which doesn't meet what I need, so was wondering if there was anything out there that offered this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
labelField.setText("New text string.");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and for not laughing at my lack of seeing the obvious. Wow that's embarrassing.